# ¿Como podria agregar espacios en blanco a un string?

Tags: php

http://localhost/mercadito/categoria/index/Deportes%20-%20Arte

Lo que intento es desde la URL sacar este parametro "/Deportes%20-%20Arte"  para luego hacer un select en la BD

```
$busqueda = str_replace('%20'," ",$busqueda);
```

pero hasta ahora solo me guardar esto: Deportes-Arte
y quiero lograr algo como esto: Deportes - Arte

Comment: La línea de php que pones funciona sin problema, asumiendo que el valor de $busqueda sea `Deportes%20-%20Arte`¿No funciona al almacenarlo en la base de datos?

Comment: Pues es que deberia pero lo que hace eliminar los %20 pero no los sustituye por los espacios en blanco

Comment: A mí me funciona, ¿algún otro parámetro que ignoremos para reproducir el problema?

Comment: Al parecer creo que es mi version de php por que acabo de probar el codigo en otra parte y me funciona de manera correcta

Comment: Recuerda que muchas veces PHP ya tiene funciones para realizar este tipo de tareas, en este caso creo que la solucion parar tratar cadenas que vienen desde la url es `urldecode($busqueda)`.

Comment: Votando por cerrar como "no se puede reproducir"

Answer (score 3):

Ademas de tu ejemplo que funciona correctamente y considerando que estas usando URLs puedes usar [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.urldecode.php)

```
string urldecode ( string $str )
```

> Decodifica cualquier cifrado tipo %## en la cadena dada. Los símbolos
>   ('+') son decodificados como el caracter espacio.

```
echo urldecode ('http://localhost/mercadito/categoria/index/Deportes%20-%20Arte');
```

Imprime el espacio que necesitas

```
http://localhost/mercadito/categoria/index/Deportes - Arte
```

Comment: Gracias a todos por intentar ayudar el error estaba en otra parte ya lo pude arreglar

Comment: +1 De hecho esta seria la mejor manera, teniendo en cuenta que dicha función esta pensada para este propósito.